# Spark saves files in a _temporary folder when it used to save them alongside a _success folder

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to learn spark for a school assignment and I have a problem. In one of my sessions I ran some code my professor gave me, on a one master one worker cluster on my pc. When I ran it the output folder had a _SUCCESS folder in it and a part-00000 and part-00001 files. On a next session a few days later, running the same exact code, the output had a _TEMPORARY folder in it and only the part-00000 file. Inside the _TEMPORARY folder where 2 more folders inside each being the part-00000 and part-00001 files respectively. Any idea why that is?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spark is saving the result in a `_temporary` directory and then move them to output folder instead of directly uploading them to output.

The two stage process is the simplest way to ensure consistency of the final result when working with file systems.

Comment: Okay, but where is this output folder and why did it save it with the _SUCCESS folder before?